# MorphTo with conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am working with field `MorphTo` and I try to make conditions for the resources.

For example I have 4 resources:

Accounts

PaymentMethodCreditCard

PaymentMethodBankAccount

Transactions

Every Account can add as many Payment Methods as he wants.
And in the transaction I work with `MorphTo` to select the Payment Method that the account selected.

My problem starts when I try to create a transaction from Nova and get a list of all the Payment Methods in the db without any relation to the account.

My ideal idea was like that:

```
        MorphTo::make('Transactions')
        ->withoutTrashed()
        ->dependsOn('Account', function (MorphTo $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $formData) {
            if(isset($formData->Account)){
                $field->types([
                    PaymentMethodCreditCard::class => fn($q)=>$q->where('account_id', $formData->Account),
                    PaymentMethodBankAccount::class => fn($q)=>$q->where('account_id', $formData->Account),
                ]);
            }
        }),
```

But of course it will not work, Someone has any idea how I can add conditions to the resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you two answers. Since the question does not exactly clarify whether the Account value is changable during the edit process or it's predefined.

##### Account value does not change.

If the account value does not change after the resource is loaded, then the solution you are looking for is [Relatable Filtering](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/authorization.html#relatable-filtering)

```php
public static function relatablePaymentMethods(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $resource = $request->findResourceOrFail();
    return $query->where('account_id', $resource->Account);
}
```

##### Account value can change

If the account value can change, then you'll need to create your own "Morph To" behavior using [Select](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#select-field) and [Hidden](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#hidden-field) fields.

With Select field, you can utilize the dependsOn and options functions, to change the query results when the Account changes.